# Drop down container in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to show and hide a `div` in JavaScript. I'm using a more `a` link. When a user clicks on the link the drop down the container will be shown and when a user click on the same more link the `div` should be hidden again. Initially the `div` has its display set to none.

**JavaScript**:

```
function show(get){
                if(document.getElementById(get).style.display="none")
                {
                    document.getElementById(get).style.display="";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById(get).style.display="none";
                }
            }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="moreOffice">
 <a href="#" onclick="show('showOffice');">More</a>
<div id="showOffice" style="display:none;">
     hai the drop box is here.
 </div></div>
```

The problem is when I click on the more link the function triggers `show()` and the `div` is showing, but when I click on more again the `div` is not hiding.

Answer (score 3):

you have missing the == operator you are using =.
it must be like this .......

```
function show(get){
            if(document.getElementById(get).style.display=="none")
            {
                document.getElementById(get).style.display="";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById(get).style.display="none";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning 'display' to 'none' everytime the if statement executes and evalutating to 'true' and then setting 'display' equal to ''. Just a syntax error in your js.

```
if(document.getElementById(get).style.display="none")
```

Use this instead:

```
function show(get){ 
       if(document.getElementById(get).style.display == "none") 
       { 
            document.getElementById(get).style.display = ""; 
       } 
       else{ 
            document.getElementById(get).style.display = "none"; 
       } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery toggle function to hide and show the div

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#more").click(function(){
     $("#showOffice").toggle();
    });
  });
 </script>

 <div id="moreOffice">
 <a href="#" id="more"">More</a>
 <div id="showOffice" style="display:none;">
 hai the drop box is here.
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jQuery then do so because all you then need to do is the following;

```
$(".DIVNAME").toggle();
```

or on a click of an element;\

```
$(".CLICKEDELEMENT").click(function(){
$(".DIVNAME").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**JavaScript**

```
function show(get) {
    if (!document.getElementById) {
        return false;
    }
    var divID = document.getElementById(get);

    if (divID) {
        if (divID.style.display == "none") {
            divID.style.display = "inline";
            divID.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else if (divID.style.display == "" || divID.style.display == "inline") {
            divID.style.display     = "none";
            divID.style.visibility  = "hidden";         
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="moreOffice">
    <a href="#" onclick="show('showOffice'); return false">More</a>
    <div id="showOffice" style="display:none;">
        hai the drop box is here.
    </div>
</div>
```